# RegisterStartupScript alert message messing up html/css

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, html, css

I've got an ASP.NET application, which calls this code at some point, to display an error message:

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "", "alert('Incorrect login details.')", true);
```

For some reason or other, when this alert box is displayed, my webpage's layout is changed and some elements are not in their correct places.

Is there any way that this may be avoided?

Comment: Try validating your html first.

Comment: Could you please post some of your HTML? Or at least the structure, including the DOCTYPE. I would also suggest to include the key parameter for this method, and also use the ClientScript.IsClientScriptBlockRegistered() method before registering any clientscript block.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When the response is written, it's immediately starts executing it and that's why probably your HTML is messed.

Try to `alert` after the page is loaded.

You can achieve this easily using jQuery.

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), 
                  "", 
                  "$(document).ready(function(){alert('Incorrect login details.')});",
                  true);
```

Comment: THanks, this solved my problem! :) Waiting for timer to accept your answer.